# Android DownloadManager save file with original name

Tags: java, android, eclipse, download-manager, android-download-manager

I'm just working on the Android DownloadManager and I would like to save the file with the original file name, provided by the server.
My current code:

```
    req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                               | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
   .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
   .setTitle("Downloading..")
   .setDescription("Downloading ROM")
   .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                      "NameOfFileOnCard");
```

Now, the file name in the download folder is configured, I marked it as *NameOfFileOnCard*.
What do I have to change?

Please help!

Comment: where do you have the original filename in the header, response?

Comment: I have a link which does a redirect to the current download link.

Comment: This redirect link is defined here:   private void startDownload(View v) {
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://yanniks.de/roms/cm-10.1-ace.md5");

Answer (score 1):

Before I use code like this, you may try this:

```
 nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(fileURL, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileURL));
```

do not forget import:

```
 import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
 import android.webkit.URLUtil;
```